# Basic Bean configuration doubt

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I am following this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

Everything is working fine. The tutorial shows 3 classes and pom file.

I want to make it work with 2 classes.

However I am having issues.

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Loader
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");
    }
}
```

This is the second class

```
public class Runner extends QuartzJobBean
{
    Runner rRun = new Runner();
    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println(" Quartz Running! ~");
    }

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) 
        throws JobExecutionException
    {
        rRun.printMe();
    }
}
```

This is the  <strike>pom</strike>  bean config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


   <bean name="loader"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

        <property name="jobClass" value="Loader" />

        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="rRun" value-ref="rRun" />
            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <!--
    <bean id="loader" 
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">

        <property name="targetObject" ref="rRun" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="printMe" />

    </bean>
    -->


<bean id="myPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="application.properties"/>
  <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${props:"/>
</bean>

    <!-- Simple Trigger -->
    <bean id="simpleTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="loader" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="${props:repeatInterval}" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="${props:startDelay}" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Cron Trigger -->
    <bean id="cronTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runner" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="${props:cronExpression}" />

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
            <ref bean="runner" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT:

My issues are:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runner' defined in class path resource [Spring-Quartz.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rRun' while setting bean property 'jobDataAsMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [rRun], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'rRun' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Loader.main(Loader.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'rRun' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: firstly, thats not a POM file, but a spring bean definition file. And then, what's the issue?

Comment: @Shakedown and Saket See edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is in regard to your `loader` bean.  It cannot be found in your bean factory or application context:

```
<bean name="loader"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="Loader" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="rRun" value-ref="rRun" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

The `jobDataAsMap` property has an entry that is attempting to reference another bean named `rRun`, which doesn't exist in your bean configuration.  You probably mean to be adding your class `Runner` into your bean configuration, like so:

```
<bean id="rRun" class="package.of.your.class.Runner" />
```

This will allow the `loader` bean to find your class in its application context.